# Brook's Theorem equivalent to "Every k − 1 regular k-critical graph is a clique or an odd cycle"

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Brook's Theorem: if G is connected and k critical and k-1 regular than G is either odd cycle or clique.

I managed to prove if left-hand side then right-hand side.
On the other direction I have tried to assume for contradiction that for a connected G which is not odd cycle or clique, that $\chi$(G)>$\Delta$(G). I know that $\Delta$(G)$\le$$\chi$(G)$\le$$\Delta$(G)+1 for every G, so $\chi$(G)$=$$\Delta$(G)+1. I've shown that G is k regular.

If I could to show that G is k+1 critical I'm done, but I don't find a way. Not sure whether it's the right direction or not.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of Brooks' theorem?

Comment: no, Im looking for a proof that Brooks Theorem is equivalent to the statement:  “Every k − 1 regular k-critical graph is a clique or an odd cycle”